# Average the score of subqueries, excluding the weight of not applicable ones

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build a custom score on my index. The score is based on several criteria, say (don't mind if this is actually relevant or not, it's just an example) :

1. Is the "size" of the item inferior to 3 inches (weighting factor : 2)
2. Is the "distance from home" of the item inferior to 3 miles (weighting factor : 3)
3. Is the "rating" of the item 3 stars or more, ... (weighting factor 1)

My score is like so : for each of these 3 criterion that match, give a score of 1. Then, average these (that is, divide by the sum of all weighting factors), but there is an extra trick : if a criteria can not be matched (i.e. "size" is null for an item, or "distance from home"), then, I have to exclude the weighting factor for this unknown.

Example : if item_1 matches all three criterions, it will have score of :

```
Criterion 1 : 1 (score) * 2 (weight)
Criterion 2 : 1 (score) * 3 (weight)
Criterion 3 : 1 (score) * 1 (weight)
Sum of weight for available criteria : 6
Total : 6/6 = 1 (fairly simple)
```

If item_2 matches criteria 1 and 2 but has no rating, we exclude the weight of criterion 3, and the score goes like so :

```
Criterion 1 : 1 (score) * 2 (weight)
Criterion 2 : 1 (score) * 3 (weight)
Criterion 3 : not available => 0
Sum of weight for available criteria : 5, as we exclude 3
Total : 5/5 = 1
```

The question is : can I do it efficiently ?

What I have so far :

- Writing queries for each crietrion is easy  : `{"term" : { "size" < 3 }}`
- Combining them together as a sum of weighted factors is easy, I did a bool query of function scores

This can go like so : each function is filter based, gives a score of one, we use the boost mode "replace" to replace any query result, and uses "should" to have the addition of individuals matches.

Let's call this query the `sumQuery` :

```
"{ "bool" : {
    "should" : [
      { "function_score" : {
        "functions" : [
          { 
            "filter": { "term" : { "size" < 3 }},
          }
        ],
        "score_mode": "sum",
        "boost_mode": "replace",
        "boost": 2
      }
      // Other criteria
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, for calculating how to divide this sum, only thing I can think of is building a script function, say:

```
sumOfWeights=6d;
if (doc['size'].value == null) sumOfWeights -= 2;
if (doc['ratings'].value == null) sumOfWeights -= 1;
// ...
return _score/sumOfWeights;
```

And compose the `mainQuery` with this function :

```
"query": {
  "function_score": {
    "query": **mainQuery**,
    "functions" : [ {
      "script_score" : {
        "script" : **script above**
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

This seems overly complex to me, and tends to become slow (esp. the script part) on my index and given the number of criteria. Do you have any (better) idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [requested evolution](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17116) should ease this kind of scenario.

It involves :

1. The ability to add a ̀ querỳ  inside the `function_score`'s functions, thus allowing to combine query scores arbitrarly
2. The ability to refer to each sub-`function`'s score by name
3. The ability to set a "no match" value (say, a value of 0) that is taken into account if a filter does not match, thus making `avg` combinations better in some cases where the ̀`weight` would not be taken into account

Option 2 pretty much gives all that was needed for the question, because once you have access to each item's individual score, you can decide which one is to be taken into account.

Option 1 allows to tackle things differently, say by making a sub-request for computing the sum of criterias, and another to compute the weight to divide it by.